# Consuming a Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, asmx, webservices-client

I have been working on this for two weeks and cannot quite get the answer.

I need to get data from a web service into a gridview, using Visual Studio 2012.
The wdls is here: https://home-c8.incontact.com/insidews/insidews.asmx
I need the 
https://login.incontact.com/insidews/insidews.asmx?op=DataDownloadReport_Run method.

What i have so far is:

```
//created service reference called icContact

//Created Credentials
icContactSR.inCredentials cr = new icContactSR.inCredentials();
cr.busNo = xxxxxx;
cr.password = "xxxxxxx";
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 27, 8, 00, 00);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 27, 9, 00, 00);

//create request
icContactSR.DataDownloadReport_RunRequest request = 
    new `DataDownloadReport_RunRequest(cr, reportnumber, startDate, endDate);`

//get response
icContactSR.DataDownloadReport_RunResponse response = new    
        icContactSR.DataDownloadReport_RunResponse();


//fill dataset with response
DataSet ds = (DataSet)response.DataDownloadReport_RunResult;



GridView1.DataSource = ds.ReadXml(response.ToString());
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

My current error:  (ds.readXml(response.toString());
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I feel  like i am soo close to finding the answer, but I dont know if it is simply not knowing how to fill the dataset from the response or if i am getting the response back at all. 
Every time I run it, my dataset is null.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is anything being returned by `response`?

Comment: Set a breakpoint under your `//fill dataset` and inspect `response`.

Comment: Check if `ds != null`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I don't have time to fix this for you, but you're never calling the service. Also, you can use a Service Reference, even for an ASMX service. See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)".

Comment: nothing is being returned by the response. At least that is what I think. because it is always null. also, I don't have a choice, because I am only the consumer of the service. Maybe, I need someone to show me the line of code that actually calls the service?

Comment: John Saunders link helped me solve the problem. funny thing- I looked at his tutorial over a week ago. Here is what I did to finally make it work.                                                                  //created service reference called icContact
//Created Credentials
icContactSR.inCredentials cr = new icContactSR.inCredentials();
      using (var svc = new icContactSR.inSideWSSoapClient())
        {
            var request = svc.DataDownloadReport_Run(cr, reportnumber, startDate, endDate);
            GridView1.DataSource = request;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
// object to InContact Web Service reference
var client = new icContactSR.inSideWS()
{
    inCredentialsValue = new icContactSR.inCredentials()
    {
        password = ******,
        busNo = ******,
        timeZoneName = "UTC"
    }
};

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 27, 8, 00, 00);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 27, 9, 00, 00);

DataSet dsCallDetails = client.DataDownloadReport_Run(report_number, startDate.ToUniversalTime(), endDate.ToUniversalTime());

GridView1.DataSource = dsCallDetails.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```